# $\left(\int_E\sin x \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2+\left(\int_E\cos x \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2 \leqslant4\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Is it true that $$\left(\int_E\sin x \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2+\left(\int_E\cos x \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\leqslant4$$ for any measurable set $E \subseteq [0,2\pi]$? I'm trying to work out a functional analysis problem and finally it's equivalent to prove this.

Comment: Can you show this when one term is zero? Can you show that the left side is invariant when replacing the argument $x$ with $(x+c)$ in both terms simultaneously?

Comment: Or translate the claim to $\int_E e^{ix}\,dx\in B(0,2)$ and try geometric ideas in the complex plane.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1190530/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3082057/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\phi(x)=\mathbb{1}_E(x)$ for $0\leq x<2\pi$; extend $\phi$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as a $2\pi$-periodic function.

Let $z=\int_E e^{ix}\,dx$. The quantity of interest is $|z|$. Notice that  $|z|=e^{i\theta}z$ for some $\theta$ and so,
\begin{align}
0\leq |z|&=\int_Ee^{i(x+\theta)}\,dx=\int^{2\pi}_0\phi(x)e^{i(x+\theta)}\,dx\\
&=\int^{2\pi+\theta}_\theta \phi(x-\theta)e^{ix}\,dx=\int^{2\pi}_0\phi(x-\theta)e^{ix}\,dx
\end{align}
where the last identity follows from the $2\pi$-periodicity of $x\mapsto \phi(x-\theta)e^{ix}$ ( If $f$ is $T$ periodic and integrable, then $\int^T_0f(t)\,dt = \int^{T+a}_af(t)\,dt$ for all $a$).

Since $\phi$ takes only values in $\{0,1\}$, there is  a measurable set $E'\subset[0,2\pi)$ such that
$\phi(x-\theta)=\mathbb{1}_{E'}(x)$ for $x\in [0,2\pi)$. $E'$ is the translation (mod $2\pi$) of $E$ (wrap the interval $[0,2\pi)$ around the unit circle $|z|=1$ and $E'$ is obtained from $E$ by rotating the circle by and angle $\theta$).

All this shows that it suffices to assume that $E\subset[0,2\pi)$ is such that
$$\int_E e^{ix}\,dx=\int_E\cos x\,dx>0$$

Now find the measurable $E\subset[0,2\pi)$ that maximizes  $E\mapsto\int_E\cos x\,dx$ to conclude that $|z|\leq 2$.

Comment: Oliver Díaz, the measurable set that maximises the map $E\mapsto\int_E\cos xdx\;$ is $\;E\!=\!\left[0,\frac\pi 2\right]\!\cup\!\left[\frac{3\pi}2,2\pi\right]\!.\,$ Is it right?

Comment: Oliver Díaz, why did you write $$\int_E e^{ix}\,dt=\int_E\cos x dx$$ instead of $$\int_E e^{ix}\,dt=\int_E\cos x dx+i\int_E\sin x dx\;\;?$$

Comment: @Angelo: In my starting argument, I show that it is possible to translate $E$ (modulo $2\pi$) to some set  $E'\subset[0,2\pi)$  so that the integral $\int_{E'}e^{ix}\,dx\geq0$ and so, the imaginary part of the *complex* integral must be $0$.

Comment: Oliver Díaz, in your proof you wrote $\,d\,$ instead of $\,dx\,.\;$ Moreover, please could you write $$|z|=\int_E e^{ix}\,dt=\int_E\cos x\,dx\geqslant0$$ instead of $$\int_E e^{ix}\,dt=\int_E\cos x\,dx>0\;\;?$$

Comment: Oliver Díaz, I would like to get a proof without using complex numbers. Do you have any idea or hint ?

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}1_E(x)\sin(x)\,dx=\int_0^\pi(1_E(x)-1_E(x+\pi))\sin(x)\,dx.
$$
On the interval $[0,\pi]$ the sine is non-negative and the difference has values in $\{-1,0,1\}$ so that
$$
\left|\int_E\sin x\,dx\right|\le\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\,dx=2.
$$
Note that this upper bound does not depend on $E$, just that $1_E$ has values in $\{0,1\}$.

Next observe that
$$
\left|\int_E\sin(x+c)\,dx\right|^2+\left|\int_E\cos(x+c)\,dx\right|^2
=\left|\int_E\sin(x)\,dx\right|^2+\left|\int_E\cos(x)\,dx\right|^2
$$
by trigonometric and binomial identities. As
$$
\int_E\cos(x+\pi)\,dx=-\int_E\cos(x)\,dx
$$
there is a value $c\in[0,\pi]$ with $$\int_E\cos(x+c)\,dx=0.$$ With the first observation the claim follows
$$
\left|\int_E\sin(x)\,dx\right|^2+\left|\int_E\cos(x)\,dx\right|^2
=\left|\int_E\sin(x+c)\,dx\right|^2\le 4.
$$

Comment: Lutz, why is the existence of $c$ such that $\int_E\cos(x+c)\,dx=0$ a consequence of $
\int_E\cos(x+\pi)\,dx=-\int_E\cos(x)\,dx\;\;?$

Comment: You have a continuous function with values of opposite sign on the interval $[0,\pi]$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is a root inside this interval.

Comment: Lutz, have you extended $1_E(x)$ to $\mathbb R$ as a $2\pi-$periodic function in order to write $$\int_0^{2\pi}1_E(x)\sin(x)\,dx=\int_0^\pi(1_E(x)-1_E(-x))\sin(x)\,dx\;\;?$$ If you let $t=2\pi-x$, you should get $$\int_0^{2\pi}1_E(x)\sin(x)\,dx=\int_0^\pi(1_E(x)-1_E(2\pi-x))\sin(x)\,dx.$$Is it right?

Comment: Yes, asked so directly it is clear that $-x$ is not in the original domain and is not according to the original idea. I'll correct this. The idea was to connect points that are opposite on the circle, splitting the interval this is $x+\pi$ to $x$. // Applying the bound to the last step will require some periodic continuation argument or some more complicated interval and integral rearrangement..